# pthread speedup for matrix add/multiply

Tags: c, pthreads

I am writing a basic code to add two matrix and note down the time taken for single thread and 2 or more threads. In the approach first i divide the given two matrix (initialized randomly) in THREADS number of segments, and then each of these segments are sent to the addition module, which is started by the `pthread_create` call. The argument to the parallel addition function is the following.

```
struct thread_segment
{
  matrix_t *matrix1, *matrix2, *matrix3;
  int start_row, offset;
};
```

Pointers to two source and one destination matrix. (Once source and the destination may point to the same matrix). The `start_row` is the row from which the particular thread should start adding, and the `offset` tells till how much this thread should add starting from `start_row`.

The `matrix_t` is a simple structure defined as below:

```
typedef struct _matrix_t
{
  TYPE **mat;
  int r, c;
} matrix_t;
```

I have compiled it with 2 threads, but there is (almost) no speedup when i ran with 10000 x 10000 matrix. I am recording the running time with `time -p` program.

The matrix random initialization is also done in parallel like above.

I think this is because all the threads work on the same matrix address area, may be because of that a bottleneck is not making any speedup. Although all the threads will work on different segments of a matrix, they don't overlap.

Previously i implemented a parallel mergesort and a quicksort which also showed similar characteristics, i was able to get speedup when i copied the data segment on which a particular thread is to work to a newly allocated memory.

My question is that is this because of:

1. memory bottleneck?
2. Time benchmark is not done in the proper way?
3. Dataset too small?
4. Coding error?
5. Other

In the case, if it is a memory bottleneck, then do every parallel program use exclusive memory area, even when multiple access of the threads on the shared memory can be done without mutex?

**EDIT**

I can see speedup when i make the matrix segments like

```
  curr = 0;
  jump = matrix1->r / THREADS;

  for (i=0; i<THREADS; i++)
  {
    th_seg[i].matrix1 = malloc (sizeof (matrix_t));
    th_seg[i].matrix1->mat = &(matrix1->mat[curr]);
    th_seg[i].matrix1->c = matrix1->c;
    th_seg[i].matrix1->r = jump;

    curr += jump;
  }
```

That is before passing, assign the base address of the matrix to be processed by this thread in the structure and store the number of rows. So now the base address of each matrix is different for each thread. But only if i add some small dimention matrix 100 x 100 say, many times. Before calling the parallel add in each iteration, i am re assigning the random values. Is the speedup noticed here true? Or due to some other phenomena chaching effects?

Comment: What do you mean by "do every parallel program use exclusive memory area ?" Each thread has an stack for itself and they all have access to virtual address space that holds the process image.

Comment: You should read Ulrich Drepper's "What every programmer should know about memory" http://lwn.net/Articles/250967/

Comment: @Rsh: I mean, if the threads require exclusive memory area to make the speedup.

Answer (score 2):

To optimize memory usage, you may want to take a look at [loop tiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_tiling). That would help cache memory to be updated. In this approach you divide your matrices into smaller chunks so the cache can hold the values for longer time and does not need to update it self frequently.
Also notice, creating to many threads just increases the overhead of switching among them.

In order to get a feeling that how much a proper implementation can affect the run time of a concurrent program, these are the results of a programs to multiply two matrices in naive, cocnurrent and tiling-concurrent :

```
seconds  name    
10.72   simpleMul
5.16   mulThread
3.19   tilingMulThread
```